# In Banach *-algebra, every positive linear functional is bounded.

Tags: fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, banach-algebras

While proving this in class, Our Prof. did it into two cases: One case was if Banach *-algebra has the unit $u$. then he used the following result in his proof:

"if $A$ is Banach *-algebra with unit $u$, then for every $x$ in $A$ with norm of $x$ less than equals to 1, there is a $y$ in $A$ such that $y^2= u-x$ moreover if $x=x^*$ then $y=y^*$"

He skipped the proof of this result and i want to prove this result but i don't have any idea, how to start. Please help. Sorry for bad english!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: define $y=u+\frac {(1/2)} {1} (-x)+\frac {(1/2)(1/2-1)} {(1)(2)} (-x)^{2}+\frac {(1/2)(1/2-1)(1/2-2)} {(1)(2)(3)} (-x)^{3}+\cdots$.

Comment: I can easily see that , norm of $x$ is less than equals to 1 so this series is convergent and making existence of $y$ valid in $A$. Infact, i can easily see whenever, $x=x^*$ then so is $y=y^*$ but im stuck in calculating$y^2$

Comment: What happens to the coefficients when you square $y$ (and collect coefficients of $x^{n}$) can be seen from the corresponding fact for a number $x$.

Comment: Got it, Thank you very much sir!